# Can't access certain services running on host machine from inside docker container

Tags: docker, networking, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

We're trying to setup a GitLab Runner, which is resposible for building and testing our web application. For running the jobs we use the Docker executor with DinD.

Our problem is now: When trying to access certain services from inside the Runner Container (docker image) we get a timeout and no response back. It includes:

- logging in to our own docker registry which is hosted on the same
  system
- wget on our domain (which is hosted on the same system)

What we can do:

- ping our domain as well as the registry
- ping other domains
- wget other domains

Logging into the registry and wget our domain is successful when trying it native on the server and not in a docker container.
So it maybe looks like a docker problem.

Hope someone can help us.

Comment: Add some more information. Piece of code which is not working.

Comment: In the docker container:

/ # ping <our_domain>
PING <our_domain> (...): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from ... : seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
64 bytes from ... : seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.097 ms
64 bytes from ... : seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
64 bytes from ... : seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.076 ms
64 bytes from ... : seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.074 ms
^C

/ # wget <our_domain>
Connecting to <our_domain> (...:80)
^C

(Seems like a timeout - trying to connect like forever)

But wget on other sites is successfully working.